# SVN using wrong SQLite version

Tags: macos, sqlite, svn

When running my svn from /usr/local/bin/ it says:

> svn: E200029: Couldn't perform atomic initialization
> svn: E200030: SQLite compiled for 3.7.13, but running with 3.6.12

What went wrong and how can I fix it? I'm on Mac OS X v10.6.8.

```
/usr/local/bin/sqlite3 --version 3.7.13
/usr/bin/sqlite3 --version 3.7.13
```

Comment: I already did - that's what caused the error.
Updated sqlite and svn

Comment: Googling for `svn: E200029:` gives quite a long list of similar problems. Chances are a careful examination of the first few will give you ideas on how to solve your problem.

Comment: see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904364/subclipse-error-svn-sqlite-compiled-for-3-8-6-but-running-with-3-8-5/30646810#30646810

Comment: Please review this link : - https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4500

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue, I solved downloading http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.7.6.3.tar.gz, unpacking the archive using tar/gunzip and coping sqlite3.c from the resulting directory into $svn-src-folder/sqlite-amalgamation/sqlite3.c.

Run configure/make/sudo make install and you should solve.

Comment: So you mean I should like partially downgrade my sqlite?
Link is dead, btw.

Comment: no, your sqlite is ok, the problem is you have to compile svn with the correct sqlite.c file .. http://www.how-to-linux.com/subversion/build-subversion-172-amazon-ami-source/ this should solve

Answer (score 2):

After re-linking subversion, I had also to re-link `sqlite3`

```
brew link --force sqlite3
```

Answer (score 1):

I had brew, svn 1.8, working fine in OSX 10.8.

I upgraded to 10.9, broke.  For some reason the symlinks brew makes in `/usr/local/bin` were removed by the 10.9 installation?

`brew update`    didnt fix.

`brew install svn`     fixed svn, or so I thought.
Then actually using svn 1.8 (`/usr/local/bin` first in my path) I also had the above sqlite error message. A newer sqlite being in `/usr/local/Cellar`, but not symlinked in `/usr/local/bin` or anything.

`brew install sqlite3`   ... didnt fix it. And I noticed brew says for this component it doesnt symlink. ok.

BUT, after that reinstall, a further reinstall of svn
brew svn uninstall
brew svn install

DID fix it.  dont know why.  Now can svn co successfully.

Comment: Had to brew rm and reinstall a lot of brewish installed things after the 10.9.2 patch - weird that brew doctor ain't complaining and that brew link tells me it was linked when it actually wasn't

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
brew update
brew remove sqlite svn
brew reinstall sqlite svn --build-from-source
```

or update your os

Answer (score 0):

It means subversion was compiled with SQLite version 3.7.13, but now you are running SQLite 3.6.12.

All you need to do is recompile/reinstall your subversion again.

Answer (score 0):

update sqlite3!!

I had similar issue on Fedora Core 20

Did the following:

```
yum update sqlite3
```

Comment: I am on fedora and having "No package sqlite3 available."

Answer (score 0):

For me, `yum install sqlite` in fedora fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This [Github](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4500#discussioncomment-8098439) post has helped me to fix my issue. It is basically re-installing svn and SQLite.

```
brew update
brew remove sqlite svn
brew reinstall sqlite svn
```