# Subclipse error "svn: SQLite compiled for 3.8.6, but running with 3.8.5"

Tags: svn, sqlite, subclipse

I am trying out the Mac OS X Yosemite beta [edit: same issue in full release], which seems to have broken my Eclipse/Subversion.  When I attempt to perform any svn action, I get:

```
svn: Couldn't perform atomic initialization 
SQLite error 
svn: SQLite compiled for 3.8.6, but running with 3.8.5
```

I have installed subversion-javahlbindings +nobdb+universal using macports, which includes the most recent SQLite3 (3.8.6), so I have no idea where the 3.8.5 is coming from on my system.

Svn works fine on the commandline, but not Eclipse.  I have looked at [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981391/svn-using-wrong-sqlite-version) and googled the relevant E200029 error code without success.

Since it works on the command line, I'm thinking there's something in my Eclipse setup which is somehow pointing to the wrong/old svn but I can't find anywhere I can change any settings that would apply.

Any advice?  (other than the obvious switching my OS back to Mavericks)

Edit:  I've got svnkit working to get the Eclipse svn functionality but still would like to figure out what's going on with the subversion-javahl for future reference.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Yosemite is no longer in beta, it has a full release. (Unless you're talking about the newest beta for the next update, in which case, carry on.)

Comment: As of the date I wrote this question, Sep 18, it was still in Beta.  Like everyone else I'm on the latest release and as others have noted below, the problem still exists, but at least we now have an answer/workaround!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused by the fact that Yosemite appears to include a version of sqlite that is earlier than the one delivered by MacPorts.  I have found a work-around to this problem by downgrading the version that MacPorts installs.  MacPorts does not have 3.8.5 version of the port, so the following steps will manually do this.  Also, the next time you do a `port selfupdate` you will wipe out these changes, so you may have to repeat these steps.

Type `sudo port edit sqlite3`

Edit the `version` and `checksums` lines to the following:

```
version             3.8.5
checksums           rmd160  b8da5ec594ac808da85469349c7506bd343946bf \
                sha256 98c33abe4106e508e73fda648b2657ac9e969fe24695f543dcde68cc71f3091b
```

Type `sudo port install sqlite3`

Type `sudo port upgrade --force subversion-javahlbindings +no_bdb+universal`

This will cause subversion to recompile against the 3.8.5 version of sqlite3.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted this answer since it applied to my question, using macports. For those using homebrew, see suyanlu's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this problem.

replace version to 3.8.5.0, it's ok.

1, `# brew uninstall sqlite`

2, `# brew uninstall subversion`

3, `# brew edit sqlite`

modify following content:

```
  3 class Sqlite < Formula
  4   homepage "http://sqlite.org/"
  5   url "https://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-autoconf-3080500.tar.gz"
  6   version "3.8.5.0"
  7   sha1 "7f667e10ccebc26ab2086b8a30cb0a600ca0acae"

 34   resource "docs" do
 35     url "https://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-doc-3080500.zip"
 36     version "3.8.5.0"
 37     sha1 "c5655a4004095c50dc8403661e0ed02fd4191d57"
 38   end
```

like vim , :wq to save changes and quit.

4, `# brew install --universal --java subversion`

5, `# rm -f /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib`
    delete symbolic link file;

6, `# sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/Extensions
    # sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib`

7, reboot Eclipse, it's OK.

Comment: Thanks for this answer which looks similar to Sean Haynes's answer for Macports, but is applicable to Homebrew.  I accepted Sean's answer since my initial question indicated macports, but this looks equally valid!

Comment: This worked for me with Big Sur. Had to edit the sqlite version to match MacOS which is 3.32.3. url "https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320300.tar.gz"
  version "3.32.3"
  sha256 "a31507123c1c2e3a210afec19525fd7b5bb1e19a6a34ae5b998fbd7302568b66"

Answer (score 1):

See if you can run this command from command line:

$ svn --version --verbose

This will show all the libraries that are loaded which should show you where SQLite is coming from.  I'd also see if MacPorts has any updates or pending patches to the port file.  Maybe there are different build/link options needed now.  I'd file a bug in their tracker if you cannot find anything.

I recall seeing errors like this in the past, but I have been using Homebrew for a while and the build process is different.

I have not tried on Yosemite.

Comment: svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)
       compiled Sep 17 2014, 20:10:14 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
    <snip>
    * linked dependencies:
      - APR 1.5.1 (compiled with 1.5.1)
      - APR-Util 1.5.3 (compiled with 1.5.3)
      - SQLite 3.8.6 (compiled with 3.8.6)

Comment: The commandline one works fine. The problem is that Eclipse is apparently not using the same svn as the commandline.

Comment: If MacPorts installed the javahl library then it should be using same version, but it is possible something about JNI impacts library loading.

Answer (score 1):

I am on latest public Yosemite + MacPorts everything updated, Eclipse Luna 4.4 (STS 3.6.1), subclipse 1.10.5.

```
$ /usr/bin/sqlite3 --version
3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57 c8ade949d4a2eb3bba4702a4a0e17b405e9b6ace

$ /opt/local/bin/sqlite3 --version
3.8.6 2014-08-15 11:46:33 9491ba7d738528f168657adb43a198238abde19e
```

I have a feeling macports' javahlbindings had some references to the 3.8.5 version. Didn't spend too much time to check.

My workaround is to use SVNKit (Pure Java) SVNKit v1.8.5.10237.
Eclipse->Preference->Team->SVN->SVN Interface->change from javahl to SVNKit
SVNKit is one of the Subclipse's feature. (SVNKit Client Adapter (Not Required))

Comment: Thanks... like you I got svnkit working so this is still in the "unsolved but no longer blocking" category.

Comment: Same problem here, however I've never been able to use SVNKit as it always fails on svn:externals.

Answer (score 1):

I've been relying on Macports for the java HL for Eclipse Luna, and after I updated to Yosemite I, too, ran into the same problem.  I use subversive instead of subclipse, but the error was the same.  I decided to give Homebrew a try and to my surprise the SQLite error went away.

```
$ brew install --java subversion
$ brew options subversion # shows your options
$ brew install --universal --java subversion # Got Warning: subversion-1.8.10_1 already installed 
$ sudo mkdir /Library/Java/Extensions
$ cd /Library/Java/Extensions
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.jnilib
$ nano ~/.profile # add export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the same thing here. Fresh macports, rebuilt sqlite3 and subversion*. Everything works in command line, but eclipse / subclipse fails with

```
SQLite compiled for 3.8.7, but running with 3.8.5
```

Looks fishy that svn links with both versions. I tried adding --with-sqlite3=${prefix} to the Portfile for subversion and subversion-javahlbindings, but that did not help.

```
$ svn --version  --verbose|grep sql
- /opt/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib   (64-bitars Intel)
- /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib   (64-bitars Intel)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this, apart from using the somewhat more insecure native binding?

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem, saying:

```
svn: E200029: Couldn't perform atomic initialization
svn: E200030: SQLite compiled for 3.8.9, but running with 3.8.8.3
```

and my svn version is downgrade from 1.8 to 1.7.14 by following this post: [Install a Specific Version of a Tool on OS X With Homebrew](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/install-specific-version-homebrew/)。

But after downgrade svn, I got this sqlite error. I fixed the problem by this:

```
$ brew update
...omit a lot of output...
$ brew upgrade sqlite
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
sqlite 3.8.10.2
==> Upgrading sqlite
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/sqlite-3.8.10.2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring sqlite-3.8.10.2.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

OS X provides an older sqlite3.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.8.10.2: 9 files, 2.8M
```

after this, it works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is old, but I just had almost the same error and I couldn't make it work with any instructions posted here on stackoverflow, but eventually got it working and thought I could share what did it for me. For me the only solution was:

```
brew reinstall --build-from-source subversion
```

I couldn't really change the version of sqlite from brew because I have other packages using it, and anyway the svn from homebrew is pre-compiled so no matter what I did it would always be set to this wrong version.

I guess this could be solved by making the brew sqlite prioritary in the path, but I was afraid this would then break other apps using that version...

My exact error was:

```
svn: E200029: Couldn't perform atomic initialization
svn: E200030: SQLite compiled for 3.43.2, but running with 3.39.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall the subversion by port and fix the similar problem

```
sudo brew uninstall subversion
sudo port install subversion
```